# Imprimir el input en pantalla dentro de una nueva ventana

Tags: javascript, popup

eh estado horas intentando ver como puedo hacer esto de pasar los datos tomados de un input a una ventana emergente, recien estoy aprendiendo asi que lo mas probable es que tenga muchos errores, necesito ayuda :c

```js
       
    var v1;

    function imprimirNombre(){

        nombreInput = document.getElementById('nombre').value;

        v1 = window.open(""+ nombreInput,"ventana1","width=300,height=300,scrollbars=NO")
        
        setTimeout(function () {
                window.location = "https://www.duoc.cl/";
                v1.close();
        }, 3000);
    }
```

```html
   <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-5 my-5">
                <h1 class="destacado">Impresión</h1>
                 <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="escriba aquí su nombre">
                 <button  onClick="imprimirNombre()">Imprimir el nombre</button>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una respuesta corta, con una práctica no tan buena sería que en tu head crees el script, algo como esto:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function imprimirNombre(){
            var nom = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
            var popUpPersonalizado = window.open("", "Título del popup", "width=300,height=300,scrollbars=NO");
            popUpPersonalizado.document.body.innerHTML = nom;
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Ahora, en tu body tener el input donde recibes los datos y el botón:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="escriba aquí su nombre">
    <button  onClick="imprimirNombre()" type="submit">Imprimir el nombre</button>
</body>
```

Y con eso te debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un archivo html que reciba el valor del input mediante parámetros de la url.

Por ejemplo un archivo llamado popup.html con el siguiente código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <script>

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    const inputValue = decodeURIComponent(location.search.substring(1));
    document.querySelector('#input-value').innerHTML = inputValue
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    El valor del input es: <strong id="input-value"></strong>
</body>
</html>
```

Actualiza tu función imprimirNombre para utilizar como url de la ventana emergente el nombre del archivo con el valor del input.

```
function imprimirNombre(){

    let nombreInput = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    nombreInput = encodeURIComponent(nombreInput);
    v1 = window.open("popup.html?"+nombreInput,"ventana1","width=300,height=300,scrollbars=NO")
    
    setTimeout(function () {
            window.location = "https://www.duoc.cl/";
            v1.close();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Las funciones encodeURIComponent y decodeURIComponent son propias de javascript y ayudan a pasar correctamente el valor, por ejemplo si el valor tiene espacios o símbolos.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que desees se abra una ventana emergente antes de que se redirija a la otra página a la que haces referencia con el `window.location`; el código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
             <div class="col-md-5 my-5">
                 <h1 class="destacado">Impresión</h1>
                  <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="escriba aquí su nombre">
                  <button id="imprimir">Imprimir el nombre</button>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

```javascript
'use strict'

window.addEventListener("load", function () {

    const boton = document.querySelector("#imprimir"); 

    function imprimirNombre(){

        const nombreInput = document.querySelector('#nombre').value;
        const window_config = "width=300,height=300,scrollbars=NO"; 
        const v1 = window.open("","Ventana 1",window_config); 
        v1.document.write("<h1>"+nombreInput+"</h1>"); 

        setTimeout(function () {
                window.location = "https://www.duoc.cl/";
                v1.close();
        }, 1500);

    }

    boton.addEventListener("click", () => imprimirNombre() ); 

})
```

Verlo en [CodePen](https://codepen.io/lsanchezo2/pen/qBxKbao).